# jQuery get, getting page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html select dropdown menu which when the user selects an option, some text elsewhere on my page changes.

```
$('.formload').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    if (selected.html() == "Option 1"){
      $('.optionvalue').html("info about option 1");
    } else if (selected.html() == "Option 2"){
      $('.optionvalue').html("info about option 2");
    } 
});
```

in the HTML:

```
<div class="optionvalue"> </div>
```

Instead of just passing in text here, I want to be able to pull from other html pages. For instance:

When Option 1 is selected:

```
if (selected.html() == "Option 1"){
   $('.optionvalue').get("option1.html");
}
```

I am unsure how to go about this.

Comment: With "remote page" do you mean just different pages on your website, or external web pages? You usually can't make Ajax requests to external web pages and get their content.

Comment: sorry for confusion, just a different page on my website.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Ajax method [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to retrieve the contents of the other page.

In the success() handler of the ajax call, you can populate $('.optionvalue') with the response HTML

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load html content into a div, use:

```
$('.optionvalue').load('option1.html');
```

More information from the jQuery website:
http://api.jquery.com/load/